# Is it possible to have a method in C# that implicitly deserializes an argument if it's passed as a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

## Question

I have a handful of ViewComponents that look like so:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(BuyerViewModel buyer)
```

I'd like them to be able to accept either a `BuyerViewModel`, or a JSON string representing a `BuyerViewModel`. For example, when you pass JSON to a controller method from JavaScript, if that method expects an argument of type `Dog`, the controller automatically attempts to deserialize the JSON to an instance of `Dog`. I'm trying to mimic that behavior.

The goal would be that **both** of these examples work:

```
var buyer = new BuyerSummaryViewModel() { FirstName = "John" };
ViewComponent("Buyer", buyer);
```

```
ViewComponent("Buyer", "{\"Name\":\"John Smith\"}");
```

---

### Why?

I'm trying to make a generic JavaScript method that can fetch a ViewComponent on the fly:

```js
const fetchViewComponent = async (viewComponentName, viewModel) => {
  let data = { viewComponentName, viewModel };
  let html = await $.get(`/Order/FetchViewComponent`, data);
  return html;
}

//Get a BuyerViewComponent (example)
(async () => {
  let component = await fetchViewComponent("Buyer", `@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Buyer))`);
  console.log(component);
})();
```

---

### What I've Tried

If I specify that the ViewModel is a `BuyerViewModel`, it works. The JSON string is automatically deserialized into a `BuyerViewModel`.

```
public class FetchViewComponentRequest
{
  public string ViewComponentName { get; set; }
  public BuyerViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
  //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FetchViewComponent(FetchViewComponentRequest request)
{
  return ViewComponent(request.ViewComponentName, request.ViewModel);
}
```

---

### The Issue

However, I don't want to specify the type; I want this to be *generic*. So I tried this:

```
public class FetchViewComponentRequest
{
  public string ViewComponentName { get; set; }
  public string ViewModel { get; set; }
  //     ^^^^^^
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FetchViewComponent(FetchViewComponentRequest request)
{
  return ViewComponent(request.ViewComponentName, request.ViewModel);
}
```

But as expected, `request.ViewModel` isn't the correct type; it ends up `null` in the `Invoke` method. I was hoping there was a flag or something more global I could specify so that it tries to implicitly deserialize this string into the expected type.

Is there an easier way to do this that I haven't considered? Or, if not, is the way I'm envisioning even possible?

(I'm using **.NET Core 2.2**)

Comment: Are you just wanting a generic method that can take a generic and figure out what type to make it?

Comment: Not necessarily. I'd like a solution that doesn't require me to define all possible types. Optimally I'd pass a JSON string in place of a ViewModel and it would automatically deserialize it to the expected type.

Comment: How can it know what type to make it, if it has 0 knowledge of that type?

Comment: Notice in the *"What I've Tried"* portion of my question, I define that the request should be a `BuyerViewModel`. However, my JavaScript just passes a JSON string. There is an implicit deserialization - the code realizes "Oh, this should be a `BuyerViewModel` - I'll attempt to deserialize it to that." I would like this behavior to happen in the `Invoke` method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make your FetchViewComponentRequest generic?

```
    public class FetchViewComponentRequest<T>
    {
        public string ViewComponentName { get; set; }
        public T ViewModel { get; set; }
        //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult FetchViewComponent(FetchViewComponentRequest<BuyerViewModel> request)
    {
        return ViewComponent(request.ViewComponentName, request.ViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I don't believe this really achieves what I'm after. I am trying to avoid hard-coding the type `BuyerViewModel` anywhere other than in the `Buyer` view component. The `FetchViewComponent` method should work with all view components, not just `Buyer`.

Answer (score 0):

The method needs to have some knowledge of what type to make the object coming in.

```
public T Convert<T>(dynamic obj) where T:class,new()
    {
        T myob = null;

        if (obj !=null && obj is T)
        {
            myob = obj as T;

        }
        else if (obj is string)
        {
            //convert to type
            myob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(obj);

        }

        return myob;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jake. While this may be helpful, I'm still holding out hope that I don't have to define the type before passing it. For example, if I have an `[HttpGet]` method that expects an argument `BuyerViewModel`, and my JavaScript *passes a JSON string*, the method automatically deserializes the JSON string to the expected type. This behavior is shown in the *"What I've Tried"* portion of my question. I'm simply trying to replicate that behavior.

Comment: Right its just deserializing the string into that object you can do the same thing like this : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(obj);

Comment: Sure, but that still requires me to define the type before invocation. As I mentioned above, when you pass a JSON string to a controller, it is automatically deserialized **based on the arguments of the method to which you're passing the JSON**. For example, if I sent a JSON string to `[HttpGet] void Do (Dog dog)`, it attempts to deserialize that string to type `Dog` because *that's what the method expects*. If I change the method signature to `void Do (Cat dog)`, it attempts to deserialize the JSON string to type `Cat`. I don't need to define that the JSON is `Cat` or `Dog` before passing it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, im not sure about what you need.

But here is a dynamic way to do it, without specifying `<T>`.

```
//Assume that the namespace is DynamicTypeDemo
public class DynamicType {

// eg "DynamicTypeDemo.Cat, DynamicTypeDemo"
public string TypeName { get; set; } // the full path to the type

public string JsonString { get; set; } 

}
```

Now you could simple DeserializeObject

```
public object ToObject(DynamicType dynamicType){
var type = Type.GetType(dynamicType.TypeName);
// Here you could check if the json is list, its really upp to you
// but as an example, i will still add it
if (dynamicType.JsonString.StartsWith("[")) // its a list
    type =(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dynamicType.JsonString, type);
}
```

And here is how it work

```
var item = new DynamicType(){ 
     TypeName = "DynamicTypeDemo.Cat, DynamicTypeDemo", // or typeof(Cat).AssemblyQualifiedName
     JsonString = "{CatName:'Test'}"; // And for a list "[{CatName:'Test'}]"
 }

object dynamicObject= ToObject(item); // return it to the javascript
Cat cat = dynamicObject as Cat; // Cast it if you want
```